# Mocha ignores existing .mocharc.js config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Here is my "scripts" section of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"pretest": "eslint \"**/*.js\" --ignore-pattern node_modules/",
"test": "mocha"
}
```

and here is my `.mocharc.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    diff: true,
    extension: ['js'],
    package: './package.json',
    reporter: 'landing',
    slow: 75,
    timeout: 2000,
    ui: 'bdd',
    watchFiles: ['src/tests/*.js', 'src/tests/**/*.js'],
};
```

When running `npm test` I get pretest running correctly, but mocha seems to ignore config file. Haven't seen the issue anywhere yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try running Mocha with `--config` options.

Example: `mocha --config .mocharc.js`

And your `watchFiles` option is wrong. It should be `watch-files`.

See this mocha example: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.js

Comment: and mocha seems like set file path. maybe it cannot specify test targets as directory on mocharc.json. so u must specify test targets on package.json.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your `.mocharc.js`

```
recursive: true
```